# Will Google read my subdomains' sitemap?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have a setup where my clients can create their own websites under a subdomain. In my `sitemap.xml` hosted on the root domain `example.com`, I list all clients "home", e.g. `http://subdomain.example.com`.

All of the subdomains also contain their own content. Since each of these subdomains is its own website, I am not listing their content in the root sitemap. I assume this is correct and recommended. Instead, each subdomain has its own `sitemap.xml` and `robots.txt`.

Since I am telling Google from the root sitemap to also crawl the subdomain "home" page, will it also detect that subdomain's sitemap? Or do I need to submit this to the Google Search Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach is to have robots.txt for each subdomain.

> A robots.txt on a subdomain is only valid for that subdomain.

Consider reading this guideline by Google [Robots.txt Specifications](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt)

You do not have to enter the subdomains in your root domain's sitemap. Instead each subdomain will have its own robots.txt and sitemap specified in their robots.txt

The new search console automatically accumulates all the data from all subdomains in the Domain property. Having done so, you don't even have to add each subdomain in your search console

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Google consider every subdomain as separate website. Hope it will help.

Comment: Can you give a source for this information?